# What is this type of graph/plot called?

Tags: data-visualisation, chart-design

I am creating a presentation for a school assignment and wanted to include a visual aid I have seen before; however, obtaining tips for designing it has been extremely difficult as I cannot for the life of me figure out what they are called, or even what keywords to search for to find out. The graph should be shaped like an equilateral triangle (at least in my case - any symmetrical polygon with equal sides probably works) and compares points in such a way that adding weight to one point lowers the others accordingly, and vice versa, always maintaining the same total area. It is similar in principle to the "fast vs cheap vs good" diagram, but uses weighted values, sort of like a pie chart, rather than a simple "pick only 2."

The  first image below was the closest I could think of to search for and comes from a Pokemon game. The second, found by chance on Google Images, is exactly what I want; unfortunately none of its "suggested" images led me to the answer. This has been bugging me all day...

[image: pokemon competition hall categories graph]
[image: triangle graph where adding more weight to one side reduces weight on other sides]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called a **[Radar chart](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart)** (wikipedia) although thats not necessarily super well known or a high consensus name. Thus people have come with different names over time. I've seen it called a *spider web chart* and *polar chart*, both which may be appropriate descriptions, although wikipedia lists even more names if none of those seem appropriate to you.